# Ajax and JQuery not working when submitting links

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm working with some JQuery and Ajax in order to submit a few links, and one of them is working, but not the other two.. Could someone help me out?..

Ajax / Jquery:

```
//Logout button
$('#logout').click(function(e){
    console.log('logout');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('logout.php', { data: '' }, function(data){ 
        window.location.href = "./index.php";
    } );
});
//Profile button
$('#profile_but').click(function(e){
    console.log('profile');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('void.php', { data: '' }, function(data){ 
        window.location.href = "./forum/ucp.php?i=173";
    } );
});
//Account button
$('#account_but').click(function(e){
    console.log('account');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('void.php', { data: '' }, function(data){ 
        window.location.href = "./forum/ucp.php?i=profile&mode=reg_details";
    } );
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav sub-menu"id='userSUBNAV' style='padding-left:10px;'> 
     <li><a id='profile_but' href='#'><span>My Profile</span></a></li>
     <li><a id='account_but' href='#'><span>My Account</span></a></li>
     <li><a id='logout' href='#'><span>Logout</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The only one that works, is the logout button. The other ones won't even output to the console :3. Could someone explain why?.. and how to fix it?

Also,

logout.php:

```
<?php
include 'user_functions.php';
if(!isLoggedIn()){
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}

$user->session_kill();
echo "Logged out";
?>
```

and void.php

```
<?php echo "void"; ?>
```

Comment: please be more specific, in what way do the other links not work? and besides, why are you using ajax if you afterwards just redirect without it anyway?

Comment: did you check your javascript error log?

Comment: read somewhere that maybe the underscores in the selector can cause such problems. try the ids and jquery refs without the _ maybe? Cheers

Comment: @d'alar'cop i use underscores in jquery selectors all the time with no problem. might have been a bug in an older version though ...

Comment: So nothing is even getting logged in the console right after the click?

Comment: Seems working fine, check http://jsfiddle.net/PKN63/  http://screencast.com/t/QRgxzHiku

Comment: I'm not quite sure how, But it fixed itself.. It just decided to start working.. I didn't change any code, Or anything. It just worked suddenly. Thanks for the input you guys gave. I have no idea what was wrong..